# First column text disappears in CListCtrl with editable subitems (MFC)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

In my MFC dialog-based application, I'm using a subclassed CListCtrl that allows in-place modification of its subitems. I accomplished this with the great help of tips from here:
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/editingitemsandsubitem/article.php/c4175/Simplified-Subitem-Editing.htm

This solution worked really great until recently when I wanted to give my application a more modern look by introducing a manifest file.

The problem I'm having now is that it behaves as expected only when I build with **"/MANIFEST:NO"** (project property: **"Generate Manifest: No"**) linker option.
If I change that option to **"/MANIFEST"** (project property: **"Generate Manifest: Yes")**, the text from the first column disappears.

- I've tried playing with the code to find the part that draws/clears the item's first column area - with no luck.
- I've also made the project to generate the manifest as external file too. The behavior was the same and with the same generated executable it was depending on the presence of "manifest" file.

Below are 2 screenshots of the same app, built with manifest and without - the difference is clearly visible:

- *without* manifest file created - all is fine:

[image]

- *with* manifest created - dialog looks more modern but the "Name" text is gone:

[image]

In addition I've created a solution to demonstrate the problem:
[clistctrl_problem.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/880alsghsbg4aku/clistctrl_problem.zip?dl=1)

I'd appreciate if anyone could provide a solution to this strange behavior.
I'm working with Visual Studio 2013, Version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5. Because of that "mfc120.dll" is used.

Comment: Is the code really so complicated that you have to post *an entire zipped project file*? Can't you just include an [MCVE] in the body of the question itself? I could just look at the code on the screen and tell you what's wrong. Now, I'd have to download a big thing, boot up a VM, etc. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray - The attached project is a "Complete" example for reproducing the problem. The solution is based on message handling: LVN_BEGINLABELEDIT/LVN_ENDLABELEDIT/WM_PAINT for subclassed CListCtrl and providing this code within the question could make it harder to read in my opinion. If you prefer to check the code without downloading the project - be sure to check the first link (to codeguru.com) mentioned in the question.

Comment: Get rid of the painting stuff (OnPaint). It is so painful to see it. I am pretty sure the two lines following the `//block filling redraw of leftmost item (caused by FillRect)` are causing the problem. As a commenter said in the codeguru article: _Another tip: Forget about all the painting stuff. Just declare a CString member in SubEdit1.h to safe the original subitem text and empty this text. If the user cancels the operation just restore it from the CString member._ BTW, I recommend you also use the OnClick method, as commented in the article.

Comment: @cha - After introducing your suggestions the problem remains. The text is still invisible for the first column and only the selection color is visible now (Manifest is created). Next, I've disabled the Manifest creation to check if it still works correctly like before (with OnPaint removed) - and it didn't! So it turns out that the lines after "//block filling redraw of leftmost item" work and are needed but just in case when Manifest isn't created and they make first column contents stay visible. How come that doesn't work with Manifest created?